# Binomial distribution propeties

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $P(i,2n)=\frac{2n!}{(2n-i)! i!} p^i (1-p)^{2n-i}$. Let $S(K)=K \sum_{i=K}^{2n} P(I,2n)$. I need to show, that for any $K'<n$ I can chose $p$ such that (i) $K'$ maximizes $S(K)$ and (ii) $S(K')>2n \sum_{n+1}^{2n} P(i,2n)$.

Actually, I can show that I can choose $p$ such that (i) is satisfied and for any given $K$ (this gives some interval). I can also choose $p$ such that $S(K)>\sum_{n+1}^{2n} P(i,2n)$ for any given $K$ ($p$ must be small enough), but I cannot show that these both hold simultaneously for some $p$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. What's $N$? 2. Hint: Presumably, you've found an interval for $p$ such that (i) holds, and an interval such that (ii) holds. If the intersection of these two is non-zero, you're done.

Comment: Sorry, N=2n, just edited the question. The problem is that I do not quite see how to get grip on intersection. (ii) comes from the fact that as p goes to 0, the ration of $P(K,2n)$ to the rest of the tail goes to zero. However, then it might be that $S(K-1)>S(K)$, at least I do not see how to rule this out.